# ENOENT Error when WriteFile to public folder in Meteor

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor, path, fs

So I'm trying to write a pdf file to the public folder of Meteor to serve the file to the client. I deploy my application with mup.
The public folder is located under `/opt/your-app/current/bundle/programs/web.browser/app/charts/`.

If I try to use `fs.writeFile()` in this folder it throws the following error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/your-app/current/bundle/programs/web.browser/app/charts/JjMMiHnyptmEPJz5D.pdf'`

When I ssh into the server the folder is available. But the file has not been created. The app runs in a docker container that is deployed with Meteor up.

Comment: It must be a permission problem, check the owner of th directory and the user that meteor/docker is running as

Comment: The owner of the directory is root. The weird thing is that the error remains the same if I try to deploy with mup as root user.

Comment: That's the wrong way to go - web processes usually run as limited privilege users, you should change the ownership to match the user it runs as

Comment: @Mikkel Everytime I deploy the application the map gets deleted and recreated. When I set the user 'meteor' where I deploy on as the owner of the map the error still exists.

Comment: Ok, so you haven't got to the bottom of it yet, but you should never run your web process as root. You leave your system wide open to malicious attacks. The *right* way to do it is have the folder(s) owned by the user that your meteor process runs as. If you don't know how to do this, you should find someone who can set it up for you